# TYPO3-Upgrade 4.5 to 6.2: namespaces

Tags: namespaces, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm updating an old TYPO3 to latest verison 6.2.12. As I do so I replace deprecated classes with the proper namespaces. E.g. `t3lib_div` to `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility` or `t3lib_extmgm` to `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility`.

But I cant find the proper namespaced class for `t3lib_svbase`. Any suggestions?

.

And I absolutely have no clue what I need to do with the new xclassed include.

```
//old XCLASS
if (defined('TYPO3_MODE') && $TYPO3_CONF_VARS[TYPO3_MODE]['XCLASS']['ext/foo_myfancyextension/sv1/class.tx_foomyfancyextension_sv1.php'])   {
    include_once($TYPO3_CONF_VARS[TYPO3_MODE]['XCLASS']['ext/foo_myfancyextension/sv1/class.tx_foomyfancyextension_sv1.php']);
}
```

It should look something like this:

```
//new XCLASS
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\FluidTemplateContentObject'] = array(
    'className' => 'Enet\\FxLibrary\\Xclass\\FluidTemplateContentObject',
);
```

But where is the path to my extension and the class itself?

Comment: `t3lib_svbase` has become `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Service\AbstractService`. A mapping of class names for an extension is usually found i `Migrations/Code/ClassAliasMap.php` in that extensions folder. The classes you mention belong to the extension `core`, so the mapping is in the file [`typo3/sysext/core/Migrations/Code/ClassAliasMap.php`](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/repository/entry/typo3/sysext/core/Migrations/Code/ClassAliasMap.php?rev=TYPO3_6-2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the new `XLASS` feature, you need to provide a proper autoloading, by either sticking to the convention or by creating an `ext_autoload.php` file.

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Autoloading/Index.html
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Xclasses/Index.html

Comment: Thank you. I found that out by myself two days ago. But as it is correct and will eventually help others I mark it as the correct answer.

For me it is valid to mention what @ViktorLivakivskyi said about that you don't actually need using direct xclassing anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As can be found in *typo3\sysext\core\Migrations\Code\LegacyClassesForIde.php* `t3lib_svbase` has become `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Service\AbstractService`.
You can't directly instantiate this class, since it is abstract, but you can work with any of it's children.

As for this block:

```
//old XCLASS
if (defined('TYPO3_MODE') && $TYPO3_CONF_VARS[TYPO3_MODE]['XCLASS']['ext/foo_myfancyextension/sv1/class.tx_foomyfancyextension_sv1.php'])   {
    include_once($TYPO3_CONF_VARS[TYPO3_MODE]['XCLASS']['ext/foo_myfancyextension/sv1/class.tx_foomyfancyextension_sv1.php']);
}
```

I assume, that this is part, which is found at the bottom of your files. You can safely remove it, since as @pgampe suggested, there is new way of XCLASSing, which no longer requires these lines.

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution by myself two days ago. I needed to create an `ext_autoload.php`.

You wrote "there is a new way" without actually telling or linking it. Not nice.

Comment: Well, the links were already in existing answer, which I mentioned. So it made no sense to copy-paste them. Anyway, good, that issue resolved.