# Change the PATH_t3lib in extensions for TYPO3 6.2

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have an extension for TYPO3 that don't work any more after Updating the TYPO3 Version to 6.2. The log said that he don't find the `PATH_t3lib.'class.t3lib_svbase.php'`. After some research I find out that the PATH_t3lib Variable don't exist any more in TYPO3 6.2. 
Now I have the line `require_once(PATH_t3lib.'class.t3lib_svbase.php');` that returned the error. Is there a possibility that I can simple change the require_once with the new path to the file (where ever it is) or a different simple way to solve the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TYPO3-Upgrade 4.5 to 6.2: namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670052/typo3-upgrade-4-5-to-6-2-namespaces)

Comment: You dont need to include svbase anymore. Only do //require_once(PATH_t3lib.'class.t3lib_svbase.php');

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, I think you are right that I don't need it anymore. I already delete the line with the require_once command and after that some extensions work again. But I have dependencies to other extensions from this one that still don't work and so I wasn't sure if that is because of missing libraries or other things. So it seems that there other problems.

Comment: are they selve made? what u want to do with the exensions? Maybe there are some in the repository

Comment: The most one are self made and I still repair someone, so its only time and work now. The main problem should be solved and and thanks. When i have a new error I can't solve I will ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

you should take a look at the smooth migration extension. It was made to be installed on any TYPO3 4.5 system and check before the actual upgrade is done, for any issues that might cause the upgrade to crash.
The Extension will deliver a detailed report for all issues found, so you can process it with your codebase in order to get a smooth upgrade.

I hope it is still possible for you to run this extension on an instance with your extension in question installed, so it can generate the report for you. It will save you a lot of time and nerves, if you follow this hint. Find the extension via the Extension Manager in any 4.5 Instance or via http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/smoothmigration

Comment: Unfortunately it wasn't me who updated the Tyo3 version, so I can't test your way. But it sounds better than that I have now :)